# Django - Update information accessible from a view every hour

Tags: python, django, rest, api

I am creating an app which fetches data from an API every time a view is loaded. As I am expecting a big user base, I fear exceeding the rate limit.

I thought about scheduling the API calls every hour and storing them in an object.

Which would be a convenient way of designing this, or do you have a better idea in mind of approaching this problem?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: search for django with celery

Comment: looks like something that could work, thank you!

Comment: If your view does not change often, then have the clients issue a GET with an If-Modified-Since header, so that if the view has not changed since last time the fetched it, then you do not need to return it again.  If the view usually different on every request, then you may consider having the clients pull that from a cache like [memcached](http://memcached.org/).  You can have multple memcached instances and load balance requests over them.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, you could add [`Celery`](http://www.celeryproject.org/) to your project and then make use of the periodic tasks feature.

Check it here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html